user input fields inside angular table with "add button" and results in another input fields
I'm new to Angular and i'm trying to have a table with headers (name, first name, function...) with empty input fields under each header and and "Add" button : the user would write information in the input fields then hit the "Add" button, the results should appear bellow the table in other input fields.
here's a picture of what i'm trying to do :
enter image description here
Can anyone help me please with that i have no clue on how to do it. Thanks a lot
Here what i tried already (just a part of what i want to do and even that doesn't work well ) :
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"
       *ngIf="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  i18n="headerTablei18n">Nom</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field>
          <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name" [value]="element.name" required />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  i18n="headerTablei18n">First name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field>
          <input type="text" matInput formControlName="firstname" [value]="element.firstname"  />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="telephone">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  i18n="headerTablei18n">Telephone</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field>
          <input type="text" matInput formControlName="telephone" [value]="element.telephone"  />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  i18n="headerTablei18n">Email</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field>
          <input type="text" matInput formControlName="email" [value]="element.email"  />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="function">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  i18n="headerTablei18n">Function</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field>
          <input type="text" matInput formControlName="function" [value]="element.fonction"  />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  i18n="headerTablei18n"></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type ="submit">Add</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>

